# Destroy HttpSession on logout Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, session

I'm working on a spring web project and created HttpSession for validating login and access of jsp pages. I haven't used the standard spring technique of security. However i'm setting the session on the time of login and matching this session on each webService call. 
Now on Logout i want to redirest the user on login screen and destroy the session so that nothing can be accessible without relogin. I don't know how to destroy the session.

// Here is code of setting the session

```
StaffModel  record1 =   (StaffModel) data.get("records");           // separating records

        if(record1 != null)
        {
            SessionData sessionData = new SessionData();

            sessionData.setMobileNo(record1.getMobileNo());
            sessionData.setCityName(record1.getCity());
            sessionData.setUserName(record1.getFirstName());
            sessionData.setUserRole(record1.getRole());
            sessionData.setSessionID(UUID.randomUUID());        
            sessionObj.setAttribute("SessionData" , sessionData);                   // setting session Data
        }
```

// in jsp i'm accessing these sessions

```
<script>
var sessionData;
var sUserName;
var sMobileNo;
var sUserRole;
var sCityName;
var sSessionId;

function sessionCall()
{
    sUserName   =   '<% SessionData obj =   (SessionData)session.getAttribute("SessionData");
                            out.print(obj.getUserName());
                    %>';

    sMobileNo   =    <%     out.print(obj.getMobileNo());   %>;
    sUserRole   =   '<%     out.print(obj.getUserRole());   %>';    
    sSessionId  =   '<%     out.print(obj.getSessionID());  %>' 
    sCityName   =   '<%     out.print(obj.getCityName());   %>';

    sessionData = 
    {
        "mobileNo" : sMobileNo,
        "cityName" : sCityName,
        "userName" : sUserName,
        "userRole" : sUserRole,
        "sessionID": sSessionId
    }; 

     document.getElementById("staffName").innerHTML=sUserName;
     document.getElementById("staffRole").innerHTML=sUserRole;
}

</script>
```

Problem : on click of logout button destroy the HttpSession

Help Please

Answer (score 2):

//  Do this on your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    return "redirect:/";  //Where you go after logout here.
}
```

//  do this on your jsp page

```
<a href ="logout">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add HttpSession session as a parameter in a Controller method. Do it and try:

```
session.invalidate();
```

P.S.: Seems like using Spring Security would be way easier for you, you should think about changing your configuration.